# When are we allowed to cancel factors from the characteristic equation of matrix?

Tags: matrices

Let: $$ A = \left[ 
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 2 \\
    2 & 1 & 2 \\
    2 & 2 & 1 \\
    \end{matrix}\right ]
$$

The characteristic equation of this matrix is: $(\lambda +1) (\lambda^2 -4\lambda -5) = 0$

$\implies (A+I)(A^2- 4A -5I) = 0$

But $AB = 0 \require{cancel} \cancel\implies A= 0$ or $B= 0$

But in this case, on solving we can clearly see that $A^2 - 4A - 5A = 0$ (0 denotes null matrix)

So, when does this work? When are we allowed to get cancel factors? In another question I did yesterday, cancelling the factor from the characteristic equation gave me the wrong answer.

Comment: no! in this case $x^2-4x-5$ is a minimal polynomial

Comment: $AB=0 \Rightarrow A=0$ or $B=0$ does not hold for matrices. Each factor can for example remove separate subspaces.

Comment: The characteristic equation is $(\lambda+1)(\lambda^2-4\lambda-5) = (\lambda+1)^2 (\lambda-5)$. The lowest degree polynomial that has $A$ for a zero is the minimal polynomial - look it up on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)).

Comment: @Kolja When does matrix satisfy its minimal polynomial?

Comment: Every matrix iz a zero of it's minimal polynomial. Do you know how to decompose a matrix into Jordan blocks?

Comment: @Kolja No I am not aware of that. I am just in high school atm.

Comment: Then it might be a little too advanced. To give you an example, consider the matrices $A=\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right)$ and $B=\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right)$. They both have the same characteristic polynomial, but minimal polynomial for $A$ is $x-1$, and for $B$ it's $(x-1)^2$.

To know more about the difference, i suggest reading on characteristic polynomials and Jordan blocks on wikipedia.

Comment: @Kolja How are minimal polynomials determined? Like i don't see why a difference is there in the minimal polynomials of A and B.

Comment: Maybe the easiest example is $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} = 0$

Comment: @mathreadler I am well aware that $AB = 0$ doesnt imply that either of them is 0. I have even mentioned that in my question.

Comment: @Abcd if the matrix is diagonalizable, then you just take the radical of the characterestic polynomial, i.e. the product of all prime factors  - in your case the matrix is diagonalizable, the characteristic polynomial is $(x+1)^2(x-5)$, it's prime factors are $x+1$ and $x-5$, and the minimal polynomial the product of prime factors - $(x+1)(x-5)=x^2-4x-5$. On the other hand, the matrix $B$ from the above comment is NOT diagonalizable, so this doesn't work. In that case you should look up Jordan normal form. Don't expect to understand it in 2 minutes, it takes some time.

Answer (score 1):

Let's review the *zero product property*:
$$xy = 0 \implies x = 0 \text{ or } y = 0.$$
It holds in fields, such as $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ because non-zero numbers always have a multiplicative inverse. So, if $x \neq 0$, then
$$xy = 0 \implies x^{-1}xy = x^{-1}0 \implies y = 0.$$
(Or $x = 0$, in which case we were done before we even started.)

Matrices don't have this property you can have non-zero matrices that do not have inverses. In fact, if a matrix $A$ does not have an inverse, then there exists a non-zero matrix $B$ such that $AB = 0$. To prove this, consider a non-invertible matrix $A$. Then $\operatorname{ker} A \neq \lbrace 0 \rbrace$, so there must be a non-zero column vector $v$ such that $Av = 0$. If you form $B$ by simply putting $v$ into all of its columns, you get $AB = 0$.

So, $AB = 0 \implies A = 0 \text{ or } B = 0$ if and only if $A$ or $B$ is invertible.

Comment: Hi, can we discuss this a bit more in chat?

Comment: Normally I'd say yes, but I'm just rushing out the door. :-)

Comment: Sorry it seems I wrongly believed that Abcd thought this. Well it may still be useful for other students of course.

Answer (score 0):

In general $AB=0$ does't imply $A=0$ or $B=0$. In your case, that factor is corresponding to a minimal polynomial and note that the minimal polynomial is the smallest degree polynomial satisfied by $A$ .

For,  here the  matrix is diagonalizable so the minimal polynomial is a distinct linear factors which is exactly $$(x+1)(x-5)$$ and so $$(A+I)(A-5I)=A^2-4A-5I=0$$

Comment: does matrix always satisfy the minimal polynomial equation?

Comment: @Abcd Yes, always, by definition. The minimal polynomial is the unique lowest degree polynomial of which the matrix is a root.

Comment: I exactly trying to type that point . Thanks @TheoBendit

Comment: @TheoBendit But Cayley Hamilton says that matrix satisifies its characterisitc equation..

Comment: @Abcd Hence, the minimal polynomial has a degree equal to or less than the characteristic polynomial (and in fact, is a factor of the characteristic polynomial).